# Buttons running out of screen real-estate

Tags: android, screen, android-studio, android-relativelayout, resolution

Hi I am developing an app which has 11 Buttons. I have created a Relative layout and arranged the buttons how I want them to be. In Android studio I am using a nexus 4 screen as a guide. [image: The Layout in Nexus 4]

Now when I run my app on screens with lower resolution  like lets say 320*480 my last butto disappears or rather goes out of the screen. As seen in the below pic.

[image: The layout in 320*480]

All my widths and heights are in dip. How do I resolve this?

Comment: use a custom ViewGroup as a top level View container

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that although using dp is the right way to go when designing for android, it doesn't mean that every screen has the same amount of dp exactly.

You can either make your layout a bit smaller for everyone or you could try to put every row of buttons in a horizontal linear layout, giving each button equal `android:layout_weight`, that way they will spread out evenly no matter the size of the screen. Use margins to control the spacing between them.

You can solve the vertical problem with weights with the same principal: put every row in a vertical linear layout and give them equal weights.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `LinearLayout` with `android:weightSum`

**1.set the android:weightSum of the parent**

**2.set the android:layout_weight of each child proportionally (e.g. `weightSum="6"`, six children: `layout_weight="1"` for each)**

***3. And use `Dimension` to give size of Button, check [this](http://developer.android.com/samples/BasicSyncAdapter/res/values/dimen.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension)***

layout.xml

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="6">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />
        ///////////////
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: for a layout he wants any xml based layout will be far too complex, the best option is to create a custom ViewGroup

Comment: @pskink I agree but as Madhav already using layout based xml, so give the idea to modify and get the desired result w.r.t all density screen.

Comment: @Squonk i'd say quite the opposite, try to count the #lines in your .xml and my .java